# If I vote to migrate, does it appear in the pending flags list?

Tags: support, flags, migration, vote-to-close, 10k-tools

I have just voted to migrate [PHP unlink() deleting file user has no permission to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860150/php-unlink-deleting-file-user-has-no-permission-to) to ServerFault because it seems to me that this is where it belongs, based on the comment exchange on the question.

Now I have done this, does this appear in the flags list under "tools"?

When I'm flicking through this list I often see `off topic; belongs on xxx` flags that have been raised, but are these questions that have been *flagged* by users that do not have enough rep to cast a proper close vote (I can't even remember if I had the option when I didn't have enough rep?), or does it also include "proper" close/migrate votes?

It seems a little silly if not - users would potentially have to wait a long time for enough users with enough rep to visit the question and also cast a close vote. Which may not even happen at all, ever, if the question does not get enough hits.

This is almost definitely a dupe, but I can't find it and I just haven't had enough downvotes recently. Let the downvoting commence... :-P

Comment: There's a "close" tab in the 10k tools. I don't think the flags queue lists proper close votes.

Comment: Aha. So there is. Never even noticed it. *And* if I've not noticed it, chances are others haven't either, which still leaves the `users would potentially have to wait a long time...` issue at the forefront. I'm not going to add a new feature request to make these more obvious because that would just be counter productive - but I do still feel some benefit could be gained by rearranging that tab layout, it's not immediately apparent how it works. To me, anyway. But then I am basically a gibbering idiot (PHP developer).

Answer (score 1):

When users without the [close/re-open vote privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) flag a question, the system creates an close review task that is added to the close votes review queue.

On the question itself user with that same privilege will see the number of close votes a question has after the close link. Users without that privilege will not see if a questions is already flagged or how many flags there are already raised. Extra flags do **not** increase the priority in the close vote queue. Recent close votes might. Also worth mentioning that close flags never end up in the moderator queue, as opposed to other flags. So to get a question closed you have to rely on community members.

The pending flags list on the 10K-tools page has been disabled for awhile now so you will not find *flags* there. You can find posts with close votes on the [close tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last2days).

[image]

It depends a bit per site but if the close vote queue is reasonable sized and/or the question has a high-traffic tag, the chances are high enough voters (5 to get something closed/migrated, 3 to leave open/reject your flag) will come along within the time it takes for your vote to age away. Currently close votes age away [after 14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting/250453#250453).

On some sites chat rooms are open to help moderating. On Stack Overflow there is [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) who accept cv-pls request for low-traffic and/or fresh posts that needs a timely response. Before you post in any chat room make sure you have checked their rules as not all rooms are open for this.