# Include close vote sort by creation date

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, 10k-tools

In the 10k tools, we only get a limited number of returned results, with little control over which posts are returned.

Given that [Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting), it would be nice if the 10k tools allowed users to hone in specifically on the questions that are at risk of having the close votes age away.

I am trying to avoid the problem of "close votes age away not because people want to leave the questions open, but because the questions simply haven't yet been looked at".

Currently, the 10k tools have lots of ways for us to see the questions that have **recently** been close voted, but because of vote ageing, what we really want to see are questions that have been close voted **as long ago as possible**, to make sure a decision gets **pro-actively** made, not left open by default.

Essentially, I want to give more visibility on questions that [fit under the the following SEDE criteria](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/322478/close-voted-questions-at-risk-of-aging-away), without having to wait for Sunday for the returned questions to reset.

<sub>I considered posting this on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), as it's not really a problem for smaller sites, but I figured that if it happened it would probably be a network wide change, and it might matter on the [largest non-Stack Overflow sites.](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)</sub>

Response to @Oded: The CV queue does not take care of this case because the secret sauce that decides which questions pop up in review often tends towards newer questions, not older ones. Additionally, at least on Stack Overflow, the number of questions up for review is dwarfed by the number of reviews that occur. [On a high-review day, we are lucky to get 4000 reviews](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/321547#graph), which has mostly been happening recently because [we are in the middle of an enormous burnination effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal). If not in this effort, we would be lucky to get 2000 reviews in one day, which is only a quarter of the number of tasks under review. However, we still typically have somewhere between 7000 and 10000 questions that need to be reviewed, so, on average, half of those questions get one reviewer per day - which won't close a post, because you need 5 reviewers. [This is why the SO Close Vote Reviewers chatroom colludes to make sure everyone is working on the same tags, using a SEDE query to choose which tags to work on](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/23470022#23470022). The proof is in the pudding - the active reviewers wouldn't take such steps if it weren't necessary to actually get questions closed.

Comment: I thought the close queue takes care of this issue - can you explain why that is not the case?

Comment: That response highlights one of the reasons why close-vote aging is a Bad Thing.