# Apparently I'll be able to close-vote the same question again

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

This can't be right. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832133/cannot-get-prefilled-url-for-multiple-calendar-events) today, and figured it should be closed as "no longer reproducible". Apparently I thought the same thing previously - I'd already voted to close it.

> **You have already voted to close this question, but you may vote again in 8 hours**

But the message doesn't add up.

- If I've already voted to close a question, would I ever get another vote on it?
- If I was to get to vote again, why in "8 hours"? I originally voted on Jun 2 at 15:32, and received the message Jun 30 at 14:22. (Double-checked at 14:50... still says 8 hours).

[image: Well golllleeee]

Comment: ^ Not only you can vote again, you appear to have voted two times already and going to vote the third time :)

Comment: @nicael - hehe, I must really want that thing out of the way! I'm a bit OCD when it comes to keeping my favourite tags well sorted.

Answer (score 4):

Your close vote aged away over time. When that happens, you're [allowed to re-cast it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting).

Comment: Um, Anna... Why not mark it as dupe instead?

Comment: @nicael Because... it's not a dupe? A feature described in that post explains what happened here, but it's not the same question or the same request.

Comment: How is it not a dupe? That question clearly explains why the user there can vote again. It answers this question.

Comment: Thanks Anna! (and Hi!) As for dupe... not knowing ahead of time about aging, that other question did not come up in my searches. I used the received message - if it had been included as "what you'll see" info in Shog9's post, then bingo. Still, I'm going to check later today to see if '8 hours' becomes smaller - if it ticks down, I'm happy with a dup + I'll update the other q so users in the same situation find it easier.