# How do Close Votes and Close Votes Review interact? Aren't Close Votes the same as Close Review votes?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

We already have canonical answers on [how Close Votes work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question) and [how Review queues work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work). This one is intended to hold one regarding their connection & interaction.

Close votes and Close Review are definitely connected, but the nature of the connection remains a mystery - [which leads to confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300624/review-completed-but-the-question-still-shows-close-votes-edit-action-isnt-sho/300851#300851).

Specifically, Close votes and close Review votes appear to be one and the same:

- The close reason selection UI is identical
- "Previous votes" seen in the UI in both cases always have have the same number and distribution
- The numbers of both types of votes appear to always be the same

However:

- Sometimes, discrepancies occur between the numbers
- Voting to close initiates Close Review, but finishing the Close Review with "keep" doesn't make the Close Votes disappear

Which is counterintuitive and thus appears to be a bug (which, as [the linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300624/review-completed-but-the-question-still-shows-close-votes-edit-action-isnt-sho/300851#300851) showed, it is not) or a bias in the system.

So, how do the mechanisms interact? Specifically, how are the two close vote types related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close votes are distinct from close Review votes, although the two notions are closely connected. Identical UI makes this even more confusing.

- **When a user flags a question for closure / casts the initial close vote**

  - The question goes into the Close Review queue
  - If the user has the [close privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), it also registers a close vote with the stated reason

    - regardless of whether the user used the "close" or "flag" link (so, for such users, the two are identical as far as closure is concerned)
  - If the user doesn't have the privilege (and thus can only flag), it only sets the suggested close reason for the review item
- **When further close votes are cast**

  - they do not add to close Review votes
  - The "previous votes" in the close reason selection UI are taken from existing close votes
- **When close Review votes are cast**

  - they also register as close votes
  - The "previous votes" in the close reason selection UI are taken from existing close votes
- **When an "Edit" is chosen and submitted from the Review UI while the review is still active**

  - An Edit vote is registered in review results
  - The review is instantly complete with "keep open" result (see below for consequences)
- **When the [close criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question) are met during a review**
  <sub>I.e. (as of this writing) 5 close votes (=(due to the above) 5 votes to close, regardless of their origin) or a binding vote by a ♦ mod (or [gold badge holder, if it's a dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/274165)).</sub>

  - the question is put on hold
  - close votes disappear
  - review is marked complete, its results can still be viewed

    - the review results only show actions taken from the Review UI, not actions taken outside of review, such as close votes cast directly or flags raised
  - close reason is selected from close votes ([details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300624/review-completed-but-the-question-still-shows-close-votes-edit-action-isnt-sho/300851#300851); <sub>(strangely, this doesn't appear to be documented anywhere else)</sub>)
- **When the review reaches consensus to keep open**
  <sub>(As of this writing, this means 3 "keep open" votes or a binding vote by a ♦ mod.)</sub>

  - review is marked complete etc. (see above)
  - existing close votes do not disappear

    - but [are subject to be aged away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting)
    - when another close vote is cast

      - a new, empty, Close Votes Review entry is created for the same question. Reason selection UI shows all close votes that still exist.
      - if [close criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question) are met - with "old" and "new" votes combined -

        - the question is still closed, ignoring any opposing votes in Review
          *This essentially makes the system biased towards closing questionable questions.* <sub>(On a brighter note, this also compensates for the similarly powerful "Edit" Review option.)</sub>

<sub>(Credits: based on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300851/648265)</sub>