# Can't re-flag aged-away flag

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, aged-away

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316963/search-contents-of-word-documents-without-opening-the-doc) (as duplicate) 2014-12-05, a few hours after it was posted, and the flag is marked aged away. But I can't re-flag that post for any type of closure, even though [Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting) quite definitely says that I should:

> 2. Allow re-casting votes that've aged away after 14 days. That is, 14 days (use the same site-configurable value used in #1 here) after your vote has aged away, you're free to cast the same vote again.
>
> […]
>
> For consistency, both of these changes should be applied to Close Votes, Close Flags, and Reopen Votes.

Why can't I?

Comment: When exactly did you flag it? You can see this in your profile page --> votes tab.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Added. As I understand it and remember from the time that feature was added, all past flags and votes were aged away starting 14 days after the change was made, or something like that.

Comment: hmm... see [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting#comment819152_250453) - maybe there is really a bug here. Let's hope this will get some official attention soon.

Comment: Reproduced: I can't recast any of the aged away close flags on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was indeed a bug in the logic that renders the flagging options. A fix will be rolled out with the next build (build rev `2015.9.21.3705` on MSE/MSO, `2015.9.21.2835` on sites).

Comment: Are you allowed to reduce the average time for bug fix like that?? :-D