# Misleading banner: A retracted reopen vote means that you can't then vote to close the reopened question?

Tags: bug, voting, vote-to-close, wording, vote-to-reopen

I found a strange bug the other day.

There was a poorly formatted/asked question, on a site<sup>1</sup> (that I am not a moderator of), that I voted to close. It was closed eventually with another two votes (only three votes are required on this particular site).

There was then an edit to the question, which put it in to the reopen queue, that I reviewed, and I voted to reopen.

Then, after some thought, I realised that the edit was not sufficient and that the question *shouldn't* be re-opened, after all - so I **retracted** my re-open vote.

Regardless, enough users voted to re-open the question.

Once it was re-opened (and it was obvious that no answer could be  provided), I attempted to vote to close (using the "close" link under the question, as the question was not in a review queue now). However, when I tried vote ("Not enough details" and hit the close button), I wasn't allowed and a banner/dialog showed up saying something like (I, unfortunately, didn't take a screenshot)

> As you've retracted *your previous close vote*, you can't vote again

However, I had retracted the re-open vote, not the close vote, <strike>so I shouldn't be restricted from re-voting to close (a second time), once the question had been re-opened</strike>.

Apparently (re. the comments), the message *should* have been more along the lines of:

> You can not vote to close a second time

and not mention the retraction at all, as it is irrelevant.

This wasn't a one off occurrence, I tried to vote to close multiple times over the next couple of hours (thinking that maybe there was a time-out), but I wasn't able to *and got the same repeated message*.

Finally, the question got re-closed anyway.

##### Summary

Repro steps:

1. Vote to close
2. Vote to re-open the now closed question
3. Retract re-open vote
4. Try to vote to close, once question has been re-opened -  you will see the misleading banner.

---

<sup>1</sup> I can provide a link to the question, but as it wasn't mine I don't particularly want to "name and shame".

Comment: You can't vote to close a question twice (unless your first vote expired): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250453/295232. That said, the error message is misleading indeed.

Comment: Oh really..? I didn't know that. Hmm, maybe I should change the question to focus on the misleading message dialog/banner then? It definitely mentioned "retracted", which should have nothing to do with it then.

Comment: The bug is just in the wording on the error message, you should have seen something different.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda - ok, cool, I've crudely refactored the question