# Does a flag get stuck on pending if the post is migrated?

Tags: support, flags, migration

So I followed the FAQ's migration flow chart, and flagged a post—custom flag/"in need of moderator intervention" since the only *migrate to* option is to the local meta—for it to be migrated if the mods (original and target) agree, and I followed the post and it was migrated:

> [image: migration notification]

But the flag is stuck on pending. I [asked](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61153023#61153023) the moderator that migrated it if it's stuck, but I haven't received a reply yet.

I know I can use the noredirect=1 to get back to the post where I could just retract the flag instead of have it age away [aged-away](/questions/tagged/aged-away).

Do attention flags indeed get stuck when migrated as I suspect? (I'm asking in general, not for this particular flag.)

---

The only [topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142657/392799) I could [find](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bflags%5D%20%5Bmigration%5D%20pending%20created%3A..2022-5-18%20is%3Aq), if I understand it correctly, is whether or not a pending flag shows, which in my case it does, and the issue here is whether it's stuck/[bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: I believe this is so: moderator attention flags aren't cleared in basically any case where they otherwise would be, to ensure moderators explicitly handle them. (There was a past bug where question closure would dismiss custom flags, but that was fixed.)

Comment: Also, "in need of moderator intervention" (i.e. "custom") flags never age away.

Comment: Without being a moderator on the site where you raised the flag, it's not possible for us to say if the flag is actually "stuck" or if it's still in the queue and the moderator who migrated the question just forgot to manually mark the flag as helpful. I don't recall any bug report specifically regarding flags and migrated questions, but that doesn't mean there's not. It's definitely not "normal" for such flags to get "stuck", but it's quite possible for the handling moderator to be moved off the page where they are taking action on the question and no long have the flag in front of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your custom mod flag is still visible to the Aviation site's moderators in their flag dashboard and on the [migration stub for that question on Aviation.SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/93213/30166) (which the flag dashboard shows/links to above the content of the flag). Custom mod flags aren't automatically marked as helpful or declined by migrations; after all, sometimes the issue may still need mod attention.

In this case, since the requested action has been taken by a mod (and they just presumably forgot to act on the flag), I've marked your flag as helpful.